# Custom order of posts in wp_query and different taxonomies

Tags: wp-query, order

Say I have the following:

- Post IDs: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
- Category: A, B, C, D, E

I want to create

- A page that will contain Taxonomy A and have the following Post IDs in the following order: 4, 6, 3, 8, 9
- A page that will contain Taxonomy B and have the following Post IDs in the following order: 5, 1, 3, 4, 3

Anyway to go about this? I can't use order / orderby here, no?

Comment: Is the order in each taxonomy arbitrary? Is there anything that means 4 should come before 6 in Taxonomy A? Like the name, a price, a date, or some other field?

Comment: It's all arbitrary so I can't use the order / orderby aegument here.